# Tcpdump not being able to write pcap file. Permission denied

Tags: java, tcpdump

I am developing a network monitoring solution for my Java application so I can sniff packets on my machine interfaces and dump the result in rolling PCAP files. When launching the tcpdump command (using sudo) from the Java code, I get `tcpdump: /path/to/app/log/GTP00: Permission denied`

**DETAILS**

The command is executed using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)` where `command` is a String valued `sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -w /path/to/app/log/GTP -W 50 -C 20 -n net 10.246.212.0/24 and ip`

The user launching the Java app is "testUser" which belongs to group "testGroup". This user  is allowed to sudo tcpdump.

The destination dir has the following attributes:

`[testUser@node ~]$ ls -ld /path/to/app/log
drwxrwxr-x. 2 testUser testGroup 4096 Feb  4 15:40 /path/to/app/log`

**MORE DETAILS**

Launching the command from the command line SUCCESFULLY creates the pcap file in the specified folder.

`[testUser@node ~]$ ls -l /path/to/app/log/GTP00
-rw-r--r--. 1 tcpdump tcpdump 1276 Feb  4 16:12 /path/to/app/log/GTP00`

I have developed a simplified Java app for testing purposes

```java
package execcommand;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ExecCommand {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            String command;
            String line;
            String iface = "eth0";
            String capturePointName = "GTP";
            String pcapFilterExpression = "net 10.246.212.0/24 and ip";
            int capturePointMaxNumberOfFilesKept = 50;
            int capturePointMaxSizeOfFilesInMBytes = 20;

            command = "sudo tcpdump -i " + iface + " -w /path/to/app/log/"
                    + capturePointName + " -W " + capturePointMaxNumberOfFilesKept + " -C "
                    + capturePointMaxSizeOfFilesInMBytes + " -n " + pcapFilterExpression;

            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.err.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ExecCommand.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

This test program, launched by the same user, SUCCESFULLY creates the pcap file in the specified folder.

`[testUser@node ~]$ ls -l /path/to/app/log/GTP00
-rw-r--r--. 1 tcpdump tcpdump 1448 Feb  4 16:21 /path/to/app/log/GTP00`

Then, I can infer that the problem is somehow restricted to my Java app. This is how my Java app is launched:

`exec java -Dknae_1 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<trust_pass> -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/app/etc/certificates/truststore -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=<key_store_pass> -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/app/etc/certificates/keystore -d64 -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8887,suspend=y -XX:-UseLargePages -Xss7m -Xmx64m -cp /path/to/app/lib/knae.jar:/path/to/app/lib/xphere_baseentity.jar:/path/to/app/lib/mysql.jar:/path/to/app/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/path/to/app/lib/tools.jar:/path/to/app/conf:/path/to/app/lib/pcap4j-core-1.7.5.jar:/path/to/app/lib/pcap4j-packetfactory-static-1.7.5.jar:/path/to/app/lib/jna-5.1.0.jar:/path/to/app/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/path/to/app/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar com.app.package.knae.Knae knae_1`

**UPDATE**

I am able to write the pcap file within `/tmp`.
I have also tried giving 777 permissions to `/path/to/app/log` to no avail.
These are the attibutes of both dirs:

```
[testUser@node ~]$ ls -ld /tmp
drwxrwxrwt. 10 root root 4096 Feb  6 10:13 /tmp
[testUser@node ~]$ ls -ld /path/to/app/log
drwxrwxrwx. 2 testUser testGroup 4096 Feb  6 09:25 /path/to/app/log
```

I will provide any additional information as needed.

Why is tcpdump complaining about not being able to write this file?

Comment: What happens if you run this from root instead of sudo? Also check writes on `/path/to/app/log/GTP ` maybe it's readonly `ls -l`

Comment: @deathangel908 It turns out that SELinux was the cause of this error. I have deactivated it and the PCAP file is written without further problems. Thus, I now only need to properly tune SELinux so tcpdump is able to write in /path/to/app/log dir.

Answer (score 0):

- Use absolute paths in command line instead of "`sudo`" and "`tcpdump`"
- Use `ProcessBuilder.class` instead of `Runtime.exec()` because you can specify the working directory, you can use spaces in options and more.
- In tcpdump command you have to use `-Z` flag to specify user because PCAP uses different than caller one. Check this link on ServerFault: [tcpdump permisson denied](https://serverfault.com/questions/478636/tcpdump-out-pcap-permission-denied)

Comment: Didn't work. I used complete paths for "sudo" and "tcpdump", used ProcessBuilder to create the Process (aesthetic change) and used -Z option with both "testUser" and "root". The result is no different, same error obtained.

Comment: @adrikayak not aesthetic, cos the expression part of tcpdump contains spaces. The "net 10.246.212.0/24 and ip" is 4 different command line option if you use `Runtime.exec()`, and one if you use `myProcessBuilder.command("net 10.246.212.0/24 and ip");`